# Error building jar file with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, noclassdeffounderror

So i created a project on eclipse, and i want to create a JAR file with it.
The project folder contains the following folders:

- src (contains two packages)
- JRE System libraries
- Referenced Libraries ("jasypt-1.9.2.jar" and "json_simple-1.1.jar")
- libs (again: "jasypt-1.9.2.jar" and "json_simple-1.1.jar")
- resources (containing images and files)

If i go to: rclick on Project's name -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries

I see both libraries correctly added to the Build Path.

Then i go to rclick on Project's name -> export -> JAR file
and here i export everything (just to be sure..!). Then i put the MainClass as entry point and then the JAR file is created without any problem.

When i extract the JAR file (registry.jar), i see that it contains everything it needs: 
[package1, package2, META-INF, libs, resources, .classpath, .project]

Also, the .classpath is correct (at least, seems to me.. not 100% sure!):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/jasypt-1.9.2.jar"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/json_simple-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

BUT THEN when i go to execute the registry.jar file from command line (both Windows and Ubuntu), like this:

```
java -jar registry.jar
```

i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException
at ...
at ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run<Unknown Source>
at ...
at ...
... lots more
```

The program compile and works perfectly inside eclipse. 
I just can't figure out what's the problem...

Comment: I think the referenced post will solve your problem. Having jars within a jar is not the usual thing to do.

Comment: extract your jar file and check the libraries exist or not by executing the command jar -xtvf <jarfilename.jar>

Comment: @RobertMoskal thank you but it's not the same problem. I'm trying to generate the JAR directly from eclipse, then run it.

Comment: I think it is the same problem.  You are generating the jar and then trying to run it outside of eclipse.  Having jars in the lib directory of a jar requires a special technique like using onejar.

Answer (score 0):

The `.classpath` file has no meaning for Java. It is only used by Eclipse. Java does not recognize that the needed libraries are under the `lib` entry in the Jar file.

You'd have to include the path of the libraries through the command:

`java -jar registry.jar -cp lib`

where  in this case `lib` is a folder residing next to the exported Jar.

If you're using Maven, you can the assembly plugin to generate an executable file. See [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven).